# Convert string of integers to time

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to convert a string to time. What would be a good way to do this? Some fields are correct, but we are finding some without the `:`.

`"093420"` to `"09:34:20"`

I have tried(not working):

```
stringvar _time:={some time field};
stringvar _ftime:=_time;
if instr(_time,':') = 0 then
_ftime = mid(_time,1,2)+":"+mid(_time,3,2)+":"+mid(_time,5,2);
_ftime
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: It gives me an error when trying to run the report and states `Bad string format` and shows my variable as "093420" not "09:34:20"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a bug... you're not using the assignment operator on line 4. Your code should read:

```
stringvar _time:={some time field};
stringvar _ftime:=_time;
if instr(_time,':') = 0 then
_ftime := mid(_time,1,2)+":"+mid(_time,3,2)+":"+mid(_time,5,2); //assignment op
_ftime
```

Comment: I knew to use it right after I declared it, was not sure about that operator when using it later in code. Thanks